# Github action error while running unit test pipeline

Tags: node.js, yaml, devops, github-actions

Since yesterday I've got this error while running my unit test on github action and I can't figure out why this error happened. Could you help me to solve that ?

```js
> whisper-ui@1.0.0 test
> react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll=false --updateSnapshot



#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: !holder_map.has_named_interceptor().
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffd7ab08610
 1: 0xb691f1  [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.9.0/x64/bin/node]
 2: 0x1bf3094 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.9.0/x64/bin/node]
 3: 0x10ac4a1 v8::internal::compiler::JSGlobalObjectRef::GetPropertyCell(v8::internal::compiler::NameRef const&, v8::internal::compiler::SerializationPolicy) const [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.9.0/x64/bin/node]
 6: 0x1e61ba3 v8::internal::compiler::JSNativeContextSpecialization::ReduceNamedAccess(v8::internal::compiler::Node*, v8::internal::compiler::Node*, v8::internal::compiler::NamedAccessFeedback const&, v8::internal::compiler::AccessMode, v8::internal::compiler::Node*) [/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/16.9.0/x64/bin/node]
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

That is the yaml code I wrote for github action

```yaml
web_test:
    name: Web Tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
          cache: "npm"
          cache-dependency-path: ./web/package-lock.json

      - name: Install Dependencies
        working-directory: ./web
        run: npm install

      - name: Lint React Code
        working-directory: ./web
        run: npm run lint

      - name: Run React Tests
        working-directory: ./web
        run: npm run test

      - name: Upload Coverage report to CodeCov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1.0.0
        with:
          # Make sure to add to GitHub secrets!
          token: ${{secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an upstream bug in V8 present in node 16.9.0. Until a new release is shipped, please downgrade to 16.8.0

Here's more info about the bug:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40030

Answer (score 1):

As Grzegorz Uriasz said, this was a node [bug introduced](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40030) in 16.9.0

Since the comment was added, there has been a new node release, fixing the problem https://github.com/nodejs/node/releases/tag/v16.9.1.

Please try using the new version, or if not possible, downgrade to 16.8.0